# How to correctly parse .ini file with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I am parsing .ini file which looks like this (structure is same just much longer)

It is always 3 lines for one vehicle.  Each lines have left site and right site. While left site is always same right site is changing.

```
00code42=52
00name42=Q7 03/06-05/12 (4L) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [52]
00type42=Car
00code43=5F
00name43=Q7 od 06/12 (4L) [V] [S] [3D] [5F]
00type43=Car
```

What I am doing with it is:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('files/models.ini', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
foreach($ini as $code => $name)
{
   //some code here
}
```

Each value for each car is somehow important for me and I can get to each it but really specifily and I need your help to find correct logic.

What I need to get:

> - mCode (from first car it is 00)
> - code (from first car it is 52)
> - vehicle (from first car it is Q7 03/06-05/12 (4L))
> - values from [] (for first car it is V, S, 3D, IRE , 52
> - vehicle type ( for first car it is "car")

How I get code from right site:

```
$mcode = substr($code, 0, 2);  //$code comes from foreach
echo "MCode:".$mcode;
```

How I get vehicle type:

```
echo $name; // $name from foreach
```

How I parse values like vehicle and values from brackets:

```
    $arr = preg_split('/\h*[][]/', $name, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // $name comes from foreach
array(6) { [0]=> string(19) "Q7 03/06-05/12 (4L)" [1]=> string(1) "V" [2]=> string(1) "S" [3]=> string(2) "3D" [4]=> string(3) "IRE" [5]=> string(2) "52" }
```

So basicly I can get to each value I need just not sure how to write logic for work with it.

- In general I can skip the first line of each car because all values from there is in another lines as well
- I need just 2th and 3th line but how can I skip lines like this?  (was thinking to do something like :

  if($number % 3 == 0) but I dont know how number of lines.
- After I get all data I cant just echo it somewhere but I also  need to store it in DB so how can I do this if

I will really appriciate your help to find me correct way how to get this data in right cycle and then call function to insert them all to DB.

EDIT:
I was thinking about something like:
http://pastebin.com/C97cx6s0
But this is just structure which not working

Comment: Are you stuck on this .ini format? It would be a lot easier to not have to loop through every setting, parse the keys, and parse the data. If you can change it, you might create an object and serialize it.

Comment: Hi @AndrewR unfrtunately this is how I get data from somewhere, I can't do anything with it :(

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Is it possible to figure out the ini key names so you don't have to do the looping?

Comment: goal of this code should be to take whole file , parse it and then insert in database.  So I afraid nope

Comment: Added example code how I try to make it.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is consistent, use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
foreach(array_chunk($ini, 3, true) as $data) 
{
    // $data is an array of just the 3 that are related
    $mcode = substr(array_keys($data)[0], 0, 2);
    $nameLine = array_values($data)[1];
    $typeLine = array_values($data)[2];

    //.. parse the name and type lines here.

    //.. add to DB
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AndrewR. Unfortunately this code returns only
mcode, vehicle_type and code. Not returning vehicle name and values from []

Comment: After deeper analyze I found out this cycle can help me to get to correct values and also have this values ready to insert to table, however I dont understand why but it change order of values:
So sometimes array_values($data)[1]; is code, sometiems it is vehicle_type, somtimes it is mCode. I dont understand why this is happening :(